# Magento - Extension that is listening on Order status change

Tags: php, magento

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1.

I'm trying to create a very simple extension that is listening for a order status change.

Here is what i have done so far:

File: /VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
  </global>
```

File: /VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Model/Observer.php:

```
<?PHP
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Observer
{
    public function orderSaved(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        Mage::log("Test")
    }
}
```

File: /app/etc/modules/VivasIndustries_SmsNotification.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
</config>
```

I've done everything by this guide: http://www.danielhanly.com/blog/observing-order-status-changes-magento/

The problem is that when i check out my system.log file there is no line or text with "Test". It seems it is not inserting this text in the log file that makes me think it is not recognizing when i change order status/save order.

Can you please point me where is my mistake and help me out resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding type as below in your events node :

```
<events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
<type>model</type>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
```

Also, to check if your code is working, add an echo 'something';exit; in your observer function. GO to backend and cancel any order. This should also dispatch your function as order status will be changed to cancelled.

Comment: I've done the changes you told me to do but it seems it is not working again. :(

Comment: I found following Changes :

1) Close </config> tag in your config.xml
2) Change your config events to following : 

<events>
    <sales_order_save_after>
        <observers>
            <smsnotification>
                <type>model</type>
           <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>orderSaved</method>
            </smsnotification>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_save_after>
</events>
3) Please check all the file permissions at the end

Comment: Please edit your answer with the new data because i can not understand you clearly with answer like a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your observer Model and app/etc/modules/xml files are proper. You need to change your  config.xml in etc to following :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <smsnotification>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>orderSaved</method>
                    </smsnotification>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Also just suggestion that you can remove explicitly mentioned object type in your Model Observer.php

You can just pass :

public function orderSaved($observer)